# Reactive Extensions(RX) Rotation angle

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

We have all seen the nice RX handling of mouse drag n drop.
I want something similar but outputting the change in angle to the centre of the screen.

Like if the user hits the mouse button and circles the screen twice I would get values from 0 to 720 degrees.

Essentially rotating the thing on screen.

How would one do that?

Comment: I haven't seen the RX drag-drop... can you post a link?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1gLmUGb

Comment: I don't understand what Rx you need to know you don't know from the drag-drop example. What are you struggling with?

Comment: Im new to RX. One addition though, I want the change in angle from the previous event.

Comment: To clarify, I want to spin the object on screen like a DJ scratching records :) Im doing this in WPF by the way so Ill have a viewmodel with an angle property that I bind the angle of a rotatetransform to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Ive figured out the last bit myself:

```
        var down = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseDown").Select(e=>e.EventArgs.GetPosition(this));

        var move = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove").Select(e => e.EventArgs.GetPosition(this));

        var up = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseUp").Select(e => e.EventArgs.GetPosition(this));

        Vector center = new Vector(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);

        var f = from start in down
                from pos in move.StartWith(start).TakeUntil(up).Buffer(2, 1)
                where pos.Count == 2
                select  Vector.AngleBetween(new Vector(pos[0].X, pos[0].Y) - center, new Vector(pos[1].X, pos[1].Y) - center);


        f.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(p => {
            game.Player.Angle += p;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the angle in radians from the center of the object. It will only operate in the range (-Pi, Pi] however. If you rotate three times, you won't get a value higher than a single rotation.

```
var mousedown = from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseDown")
        select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(this);

var mouseup = from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseUp")
              select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(this);

var mousemove = from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove")
                select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(this);

Vector center = new Vector(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);

var radian = from start in mousedown
        from pos in mousemove.StartWith(start).TakeUntil(mouseup)
        select Math.Atan2((pos - center).Y, (pos -center).X);
```

EDIT

If you are after the change in angle, the following should work:

```
var angle = from start in mousedown
            from pos in mousemove.StartWith(start).TakeUntil(mouseup)
            select Vector.AngleBetween(pos - center, start - center);
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I want the user to be able to rotate multiple laps though. Would it be possible to alter this so you just get the delta angle? I want the original angle of the object to be the starting point, thats why I want the delta.